# python: fast dictionary word lookup with wildcards*

Tags: python, dictionary, tree, lookup

Given a text, which is split into a list of words, I want to lookup each of the words in an dictionary of words, which too is read from a text-file and `split('\n')`.

Rather than checking if each word is contained in the dictionary (which is gruesomely slow) I need to select a list of elements based on wildcards* ('*' is at the end i.e. no permuterm solution required). For instance, the solution should select all dictionary elements starting with 'dep', without traversing the entire dictionary list.

Performance is of the essence in this case. I though of a Btree...but

1. What would be the best package and data-type for a fast implementation in Python.
2. Please provide code examples

Comment: Seems like you need some [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) package

Comment: The wildcard thing will always be slower for sure. Dicts work with hashes (constant time for access).

Comment: @JBernardo: no, it just means that the elements have to start with whatever comes before the 'star'

Comment: That's why you'll lose the constant time search. i.e. It's gonna be slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [dawg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph), which is more efficient than a Trie in terms of space waste. There are a few python implementations, but for a start take a look [here](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=115).

Comment: From the website: "...If you don't care about memory or speed[sic!], just store your words"... Is it faster?

Comment: The dawg is definitely faster. The quote from the website is ironic. "just store your words in an SQL database, or spin up 100 machines in the cloud. I don't mind. More power to you! "

Answer (score 2):

You want a trie. Use the [PyTrie](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyTrie) package.